# Duplicate values, multiple criteria, and countif for a particular data set

Tags: excel

In my current role, there are several times where we need to count data based on multiple conditions in multiple rows for the same student ID.

I've tried index & match, arrays, and a slew of countif functions, but nothing has quite worked.  I've researched this for hours online already.

```
=SUM(IF("EXTR"='Insert FTFTCohort FinAid Here'!$L2:$L20000,1/(COUNTIFS('Insert FTFTCohort FinAid Here'!$L2:$L20000,"EXTR",'Insert FTFTCohort FinAid Here'!$B2:$B20000,'Insert FTFTCohort FinAid Here'!$B2:$B20000)), 0))
```

This returns the data, but the counts will be off slightly.  The second column is the array results and the third column is the results using the advanced filter and then copying unduplicated results.

Comment: We will need to see your data and how it is setup.  Please mockup some data and expected outcome.  make sure to include rows that should not be counted.

Comment: I'm brand new to this.  What's the best way to show you?  I can't paste in columns or a snip here.

Comment: The best is to enter it as text then highlight and use Ctrl-k to format.